# Does this noun phrase (a variable name) take a singular or plural verb?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement, uncountable-nouns, terminology, collective-nouns

I'm writing a codebook that defines variables in a data set. Should the verb of the following sentence be singular or plural (refer/refers)? (Note that the italics appear in original; they are, obviously, the variable name.)

> *Other types of residential treatment facility* refers to facilities not
>   licensed as a psychiatric hospital, whose primary purpose is ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case where the way English handles the "use/mention distinction" is important. See, without the italics, quotes, or any other distinguishing marks, you could *use* the words directly just as you normally do and make a grammatical and almost semantically coherent sentence like this (verb bolded):

> Other types of residential treatment facility **refer** to facilities not licensed as a psychiatric hospital, whose primary purpose is ...

The only problem with this would be that the types here do not in fact *refer*; they actually *are*.

So what you're really trying to do is say this (verb bolded, elided phrase in brackets):

> [The label/codeword/phrase/term] "other types of residential treatment facility" **refers** to facilities not licensed as a psychiatric hospital, whose primary purpose is ...

Once you realize that there's implicitly a singular noun that introduces the *mention* of the phrase you italicized, but is elided in the actual sentence, it becomes much clearer how this sentence should be written (verb bolded):

> *Other types of residential treatment facility* **refers** to facilities not licensed as a psychiatric hospital, whose primary purpose is ...

A phrase that you are mentioning, not using, is considered **one phrase**. It's singular. So you use singular conjugations with it. (This is a little clearer when using quotes, since that's a more common way to mention a phrase, but italics, bold, underlines, and even different font families have been used for the purpose as well, so there's nothing wrong with the sentence being written this way.)

Comment: Thanks; this confirms my analysis — singular noun head ellipsis — and settles a disagreement.

Answer (score -1):

Subject NOUN of the sentence is TYPES.
"Of residential treatment facility" is a prepositional phrase that does not determine verb tense. REFER is the appropriate verb.

Answer (score -3):

The head noun of the noun phrase **Other types of residential treatment facility** is **types** which is plural. Thus, it takes **refer**

Comment: But the sentence is referring the entire phrase "Other types of residential treatment facility", not literally to the types themselves, so the singular *refers* is appropriate, not the plural *refer*.

Comment: @stangdon We have to find the head noun in the complex/long noun phrases to choose the right form of the verb. Otherwise, as you suggested, all the noun phrases, no matter they are, should be treated as a whole unit. **So**, we don't need to what is so-called *concord* or subject-verb agreement in this case at all !!!